# Wordpress sidebar

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I'm trying to add a twitter feed on my site, but sidebar doesn't show.
My theme was created from scratch by some guy.

**function.php**

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id'            => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );} 
   add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ) ) : ?>
<div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your sidebar does contain any content. What happens if you write `print_r( is_active_sidebar('home_right_1'))`? Does it return `true`?

Comment: Can you elaborate what I do with it?

Comment: You have to locate why your sidebar isn't shown. You can debug the project, simply var_dump stuff and inspect with web developer tools. I think you have to dig into on your own, the question isn't really specific.